# symfony is not reading the right path of "routing_dev.ym"

Tags: symfony, yaml

When i try to access my application in remote server i get this exception although it work fine in my local machine.

[image]

The right path is `..../app/config/config_dev.yml` 
but it indicate `..../app/app/config/config_dev.yml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `your_app_name_folder\app\config\config_dev.yml`:

```
4  framework:
5      router:
6:         resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
7          strict_requirements: true
8      profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
```

Comment: i find that is versionning problem since 3.3.x, (/app) must be removed when in same remote server (my case) but it's work in local server

Comment: app\config\config_dev.yml in synfony 3.3.x
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Check your AppKernel.php, there should be 2 methods:

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}

public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}
```

Check if the path is right and clear cache. AppKernel should be in

> ..../app/AppKernel.php